# Issue on Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have started my Ansible training.
I have a very simple use case: I am trying to generate html files using jinja template.
Find here my yml file:

```
---

- name: "Generate html file for each host"
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
    host_inventory: "localhost"
    inventory_dir: "/home/ansible/Ansible/ch02/var/www/html/inventory"
  tasks:
    - name: "Create template directory"
      file:
        path: "{{playbook_dir}}"
        owner: "ansible"
        group: "ansible"
        mode: "0755"
        state: "directory"
      delegate_to: "{{host_inventory}}"
    - name: "Html file generation"
      template:
        src: "host.html.j2"
        dest: "{{playbook_dir}}/{{inventory_hostname}}.html"
      delegate_to: "{{host_inventory}}"
```

Find here the jinja file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> host {{inventory_hostname}} </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> 
      This host is called {{inventory_hostname}} 
    </p>
    <p>
      Find below a list of IPv4 adresses :
    </p>
    <ul>
      {% for ip in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses %}
      <li> {{ip}} </li>
      {% endfor }
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hosts inventory is simple:

```
[ha-proxies]
ha-proxy

[apache]
frontend-01
frontend-02

[mysql]
mysql_serv
```

Execution seems to fail due to `{{inventory_hostname}}` magic variable badly interpreted:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts.inv playbook.yml
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The TRANSFORM_INVALID_GROUP_CHARS settings is set to allow bad characters in group names by default, this
 will change, but still be user configurable on deprecation. This feature will be removed in version 2.10. Deprecation warnings
can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details


PLAY [Generate html file for each host] *****************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************
ok: [ha-proxy]
ok: [mysql_serv]
ok: [frontend-02]
ok: [frontend-01]

TASK [Create template directory] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [frontend-02 -> localhost]
ok: [mysql_serv -> localhost]
ok: [frontend-01 -> localhost]
ok: [ha-proxy -> localhost]

TASK [Html file generation] *****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [ha-proxy -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: unexpected '}'. String: <html>\n  <head>\n    <title> host {{inventory_hostname}} </title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <p> \n      This host is called {{inventory_hostname}} \n    </p>\n    <p>\n      Find below a list of IPv4 adresses :\n    </p>\n    <ul>\n      {% for ip in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses %}\n      <li> {{ip}} </li>\n      {% endfor }\n    </ul>\n  </body>\n</html>\n"}
fatal: [frontend-01 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: unexpected '}'. String: <html>\n  <head>\n    <title> host {{inventory_hostname}} </title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <p> \n      This host is called {{inventory_hostname}} \n    </p>\n    <p>\n      Find below a list of IPv4 adresses :\n    </p>\n    <ul>\n      {% for ip in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses %}\n      <li> {{ip}} </li>\n      {% endfor }\n    </ul>\n  </body>\n</html>\n"}
fatal: [frontend-02 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: unexpected '}'. String: <html>\n  <head>\n    <title> host {{inventory_hostname}} </title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <p> \n      This host is called {{inventory_hostname}} \n    </p>\n    <p>\n      Find below a list of IPv4 adresses :\n    </p>\n    <ul>\n      {% for ip in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses %}\n      <li> {{ip}} </li>\n      {% endfor }\n    </ul>\n  </body>\n</html>\n"}
fatal: [mysql_serv -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: unexpected '}'. String: <html>\n  <head>\n    <title> host {{inventory_hostname}} </title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <p> \n      This host is called {{inventory_hostname}} \n    </p>\n    <p>\n      Find below a list of IPv4 adresses :\n    </p>\n    <ul>\n      {% for ip in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses %}\n      <li> {{ip}} </li>\n      {% endfor }\n    </ul>\n  </body>\n</html>\n"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************
frontend-01                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
frontend-02                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
ha-proxy                   : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
mysql_serv                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 5):

The error you are seeing is:

> AnsibleError: template error while templating string: unexpected '}'.

This generally indicates a syntax error in your template. In your case, you have a typo.  Take a look at the `for` loop:

```
      {% for ip in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses %}
      <li> {{ip}} </li>
      {% endfor }
```

You're missing a `%`. You want:

```
      {% for ip in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses %}
      <li> {{ip}} </li>
      {% endfor %}
```